# Authorizing multiple graphql queries only once

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

If I write multiple graphql queries let's say 5 in a single request. All the requests have authorization set up with JWT token. If I send the request with 5 queries, token is validated 5 times.

Is there any way to validate only once if request has multiple graphql queries or mutations?

Comment: I'd like to understand more about the use-case here, is the intention to create duplicated queries that reject after the first successful attempt? There are likely workarounds to do something like this using Apollo Link and there's an example on the Apollo blog: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/using-apollo-link-to-handle-dependent-queries/ 

Generally, the expected behavior is for a query to return any requested data.